# How to add default variable in Azure Run Pipeline Menu

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, cicd

Currently in our Run Pipeline Menu. There is an Advanced options to defined the variable to be used by this pipeline.

By default on variables section. There is only 1 default variable display and i can add a new one by specifying the variable name and the variable value. My Question is where to add another default variable which user just need to click on variable name and specified a value instead of needed to specify variable name and variable value.

Please refer to below image.

[image: Want 2 have 2 here]

[image: Want to add another 1 variable here]

Comment: isnt it just setting default property ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#passing-parameters

Comment: Hi @VovaBilyachat Thank you for your response. I try add parameter with default value. Its not display there. There is one Variable that appear there is the one use in condition like this => condition: eq(variables['BUILD_TYPE'], 'hello world')

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a Parameter as below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are not using the YAML way. you can click on
EDIT -> Three dots ->Trigger -> Variables

Else for the yaml way you need to set as per mokh223 answer